# Reloading TableView on Main Thread causing crash - iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have some heavy processing (parse thousands of local JSON objects into Array which is `dataSource` for `UITableView`) to be done before reloading `tableView`. Now when I am doing it simply one by one, without any threading or stuff, the UI is freezing while loading data.

So I tried doing the processing on `background thread` and reloading `tableView` on `main thread`, but that's causing the `tableView` reload to happen before the processing completes, resulting in crash.

How to solve?

Here's my code:

```
// Heavy work dispatched to a separate thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        temp = [ayatArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self.SratNo == %@)",mood]];

        NSSet *uniqueSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[temp valueForKey:@"Para"]];
        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES];
        uniqueParasArray = [uniqueSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

        currentParaNum = [uniqueParasArray[i] integerValue];
        NSNumber *mood = @(currentParaNum);

        NSArray *paraWiseAyats = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        paraWiseAyats = [temp filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self.Para == %@)",mood]];



        ayatArrayForTableView = [paraWiseAyats mutableCopy];
        [self.translationTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

});
```

Comment: crash log .......

Comment: The crash is regarding index out of bounds, that I'm guessing is happening because the data hasn't processed completely and the main thread realods tableview.

Comment: in numberOfRows you have to return **ayatArrayForTableView.count**

Comment: That is exactly what I am returning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code. Inside your `global_queue` block use `main_queue`.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        temp = [ayatArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self.SratNo == %@)",mood]];

        NSSet *uniqueSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[temp valueForKey:@"Para"]];
        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES];
        uniqueParasArray = [uniqueSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

        currentParaNum = [uniqueParasArray[i] integerValue];
        NSNumber *mood = @(currentParaNum);

        NSArray *paraWiseAyats = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        paraWiseAyats = [temp filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self.Para == %@)",mood]];



        ayatArrayForTableView = [paraWiseAyats mutableCopy];

       // Use block here
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Update UI
               [self.translationTableView reloadData];
            });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`

> This method registers with the runloop of its current context, and depends on that runloop being run on a regular basis to perform correctly. One common context where you might call this method and end up registering with a runloop that is not automatically run on a regular basis is when being invoked by a dispatch queue. If you need this type of functionality when running on a dispatch queue, you should use dispatch_after and related methods to get the behavior you want.